# How to force the Tailwind CSS IntelliSense extension for VSCode work with .html.eex and .html.leex files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, elixir, phoenix-framework, tailwind-css

How to force the Tailwind CSS IntelliSense extension for VSCode work with `.html.eex` and `.html.leex` files?

I same tried add settings `.html.eex` and `.html.leex` for IntelliSense for CSS class names in HTML, but don’t work for me.

So I can see this extension support HTML (EEx): https://github.com/bradlc/vscode-tailwindcss/blob/f5dfe02f74ac9bd68529f1997ae875691b819833/src/index.ts#L50

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution, helped me this extantion https://github.com/ecmel/vscode-html-css.
Thanks you so much [Ecmel Ercan](https://github.com/ecmel) and [tme_317](https://elixirforum.com/u/tme_317) for your thoughts!

But this extension not worked with HTML (EEx) files. I contributed to this. Until the author has merged pull-request, you can use my branch: https://github.com/reducio/vscode-html-css/tree/add-html-eex

```
git clone https://github.com/reducio/vscode-html-css/tree/add-html-eex
npm install
vsce package

# deps may be need, if you need hack this code
npm install -g typescript
npm install -g yo generator-code
npm install -g vsce
npm i -g @zeit/ncc
```

So, after run `vsce package` you get file `vscode-html-css-0.2.3.vsix` in root project folder.
Then you need install extension manually:

[image]

Don't forget about settings of extension.
In settings.json add:

```
    "css.remoteStyleSheets": [
        "https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css"
    ],
```

**Usage:**
You can view a list of attributes via  `ctrl + space`.

Enjoy auto completion Tailwind CSS in your HTML (EEx) files.